# Download from AWS glacier via CLI or simple linux tool

Tags: backup, aws

So I have uploaded several backups to Amazon glacier (using Synology Glacier backup) and want to check if it is also possible to download the archives with a standard Linux installation.

I have the aws CLI but cannot figure out how to trigger an archive download.

```
aws glacier list-vaults --account-id -
```

is working.

This is what I tried next

```
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id - --vault-name "arn:aws:glacier:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx" archive-retrieval
```

gives only:

```
An error occurred (400) when calling the InitiateJob operation:
```

Answer (score 1):

`--vault-name` parameter expects the name of the vault, not its ARN